# Creating a scheduled task that runs an algorithm daily to check whether an item has expired

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I am using c sharp in .NET framework and want to create a scheduled task that runs every day at the same time to check all items in a specified file are due to expire. If they are due to expire the algorithm will send an alert. I have read up on windows task scheduler and was wondering if this is something I could use in this instance or if there is another scheduling instance I could use?

I've seen code that runs an executable program with task scheduler but I haven't seen any that run a particular function.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You use the scheduled task to run your app and pass it a commandline argument. The app should detect the commandline argument and then do something specific based on that.

Comment: In that case I don't think it will work for what I want it to do. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to schedule the task in the C# application itself you could use a framework like [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). But this means your application must run all the time. Maybe creating a Windows service would be a good option for that.

If your application should be called by a scheduler I would give the Windows Task Scheudler a try and see if it fullfils all your requirements. Here is a good start on how to use it: https://www.technipages.com/scheduled-task-windows

If you need multiple different task that are all embeded in the same application, I would go with the command line approach suggested by John. For that you could use the [Command Line Parser Library](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) or something similar.

Comment: What do you mean by a window service? Quartz seems like a good option

Comment: If you schedule with your app, the app has to run all the time. To achieve that I would let it run as a [Window Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service). Here you find a good tutorial on how to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service

Just letting it run as console app would work as well. But you then have to manage the lifetime by yourself.